# Can a person release music using the name of a fictional character as the artist name?

Tags: united-states

A example of this would be a person releasing music with one of these names as the artist name: Mogul Khan (the Axe) from Dota 2, Malfurion Stormrage from Warcraft, Saruman from Lord of the Rings.

If this infringes on any rights, can this be avoided by changing the name slightly, such as removing spaces or adding numbers at the end?

Comment: Although not a character there is this - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cirith_Ungol_(band)

Comment: And this one - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorgoroth

Comment: @NeilMeyer (I'm assuming) most of the LOTR-Trademarks where only registered when the films where released. These bands are much older than that.

Comment: Could also be that nobody at the Tolkien estate has any knowledge of Norwegian death metal bands an if they did they would do a c&d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a possibility that a fictional name is also a registered trademark, for example "Harry Potter". You can check [here](https://tmsearch.uspto.gov/bin/gate.exe?f=login&p_lang=english&p_d=trmk), which will yield no matches fopr "Mogul khan" and 7 for "Saruman". The uses of "Saruman" are specifically for kinds of jewelry. Registering a trademark is not absolute ownership of a name, it is limited to a specific context, so you would need to steer clear of launching a line of jewelry with the name "Saruman".